# Алгоритмы. mergeSort на с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, память

Решаю задачи из хендбука Яндекса по алгоритмам. Мое решение не проходит тест №4 (вводные данные неизвестны) - Wrong Answer. то есть нет проблемы с памятью, скоростью. Проблема в самом решении видимо... помогите, что нужно исправить или на что нужно обратить внимание?
[image: Условие задачи]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
мой код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int* merge(int* arr1, size_t n1, int* arr2, size_t n2) {
    int* res = new int[n1 + n2];
    size_t i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while (i1 != n1 && i2 != n2) {
        if (arr1[i1] < arr2[i2]) {
            res[i1 + i2] = arr1[i1];
            ++i1;
        }
        else {
            res[i1 + i2] = arr2[i2];
            ++i2;
        }
    }
    while (i1 != n1) {
        res[i1 + i2] = arr1[i1];
        ++i1;
    }
    while (i2 != n2) {
        res[i1 + i2] = arr2[i2];
        ++i2;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int* res = nullptr;
    int* temp = nullptr;
    size_t total_length = 0;
    while (n-- != 0) {
        size_t length;
        std::cin >> length;
        int* second = new int[length];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            int x;
            std::cin >> x;
            second[i] = x;
        }
        temp = merge(res, total_length, second, length);
        delete[] res;
        delete[] second;
        res = temp;
        total_length += length;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i != total_length; ++i) {
        std::cout << res[i] << ' ';
    }
    delete[] res;
}
```

Comment: Проблемы со скоростью будут, т.к. алгоритм в худшем случае квадратичный. Однако явных дефектов в коде не видно.

Comment: А там есть требование самостоятельной реализации? т.е. запрещено испоользовать std::vector, std::merge? При этом программа ну очень похожа на правильную :)  Я бы на всякий случай убрал пробел в конце вывода, но если какие-то тесты проходят, то дело не в нем, видимо.

Comment: @mbo: _Проблемы со скоростью будут, т.к. алгоритм в худшем случае квадратичный._
Алгоритм имеет сложность O(n1 + n2). Кроме того, если была бы недостаточная оптимизация по времени, проверяющая система вернула бы TLE, а не WA.

Comment: @alex-titov на векторах можно написать, но захотелось попрактиковаться с массивами. std::merge уже звучит как читерство, в его реализации и заключается задача

Comment: Линейную сложность `O(n1 + n2)`  имеет единичное слияние, а ваша реализация поочередного слияния множества массивов - квадратичная. К примеру, если массивы длиной 1, то первый элемент обрабатывается m раз, второй m-1 и так далее. Сумма - `~m^2/2`. Можно добиться `O(m*log(n))`, если использовать бинарную кучу

Comment: @mbo справедливо сказано, но времени хватает

Comment: Чтобы убедиться, что проблема в вашем решении, попробуйте протестировать какое-нибудь другое решение. Желательно попроще в реализации. Например, сохранить все последовательности в вектор, отсортировать, вывести. [Как-то так](https://godbolt.org/z/jK67GEsGG).

Comment: Проблема решена.... косяк в проверяющей системе Яндекс (входные последовательности НЕотсортированы)

Comment: В этой задаче (с указанными ограничениями) легко получить сложность `O(m * n)`, используя n-путевое слияние. Сначала считавыаете в память все исходные последовательности, а потом параллельно идете по n входным массивам (на каждом шаге ищете минимальный из n текущих кандидатов). И  кстати, запоминать итоговую последовательность не обязательно, можно сразу выводить числа по мере слияния

Comment: При полном числе элементов `10^5` достаточно считать все элементы в один массив и отсортировать его. Ни к чему париться со слиянием.